# Polyglot Notebooks - reverse RETURN versus SHIFT-RETURN behavior?

Tags: polyglot-notebooks

How does one change the default behavior in Polyglot Notebooks so that *inside* a Code or Markdown cell a SHIFT-RETURN yields a newline.  A RETURN would do what a SHIFT-RETURN used to do.  RETURN would now, not yield a newline but instead, close the cell.

This is how Slack and every other chat-like app I use behaves and I'm constantly mixing up the behavior when working in Polyglot Notebooks.

Thank you!